Thunks in Lean4
I am trying to understand lazy evaluation in Lean4 based on this example from the manual. However, I am getting an unexpected answer of zero. Can someone point out how to correct the code below to give expected results (e.g. the 1000th Fibonacci number)?
def fib : Nat → Nat
  | 0   => 0
  | 1   => 1
  | x+2 => fib (x+1) + fib x

def f (c : Bool) (x : Thunk Nat) : Nat :=
  if c then
    x.get
  else
    0

def g (c : Bool) (x : Nat) : Nat :=
  f c (Thunk.mk (fun _ => fib x))

#eval g false 1000

Lean 4 Web link

Change false to true in the last line??

This would give the correct results, but appears to bypass memoization judging by the speed: n=34 is noticeably slow on my machine.

@hilberts_drinking_problem Why would you expect a thunk in g to influence the recursive evaluation of fib? In any case, it seems we are now discussing a very different question, you might want to adjust your post.

The code snippet is taken from the lean manual. I assumed that it was trying to illustrate how caching behavior of lean Thunks can be used for memoization, but maybe my reading is wrong.
